# How to open a string as a HTML content in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, data-uri

```
public openNewTab(blob: Blob | string) {
   const data = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(blob);
   window.open(data, '_blank');
   setTimeout(() => window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data), 100);
}
```

I'm trying to open blob file (in this example it's a string) into a new tab as a HTML content. This function works fine but it opens a plain text content and tags are just written like "`<html><head><title>....`" as a text. I want to display the HTML content. I tried to define data as text/html but it doesn't work. How can I do that without using any library?
Also I tried to use anchor tag like this;

```
   const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
   document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);
   anchorElement.setAttribute('href', data);
   anchorElement.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
   anchorElement.click();
```

It has same result with window.open().

Comment: The question is not about <pre> tag. The tags displayed as a text. I want to display the HTML content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling the browser the content is `text/plain` - thats why it's handled as text only. Change it to `text/html` and it should work.

As an alternative you can set the content of opened window with `window.document.write()`.

```
document.querySelector("#someButton").onclick = function() {
  let child = window.open("about:blank","myChild");
  child.document.write(`<html>
    <head><title>Hi mum!</title></head>
    <body><p>Hello World</p></body>
   </html>`);
  child.document.close();
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anotherCoward/j8w0t926/).

Comment: Okay document.write() works, thanks. Since I'm dealing with a parameter data which is Blob or string, how can I open HTML content in a new tab with creating a URL?

Comment: You simply can't. This is a security related question and is answered at a lot of questions related to `CORS`.

Answer (score 2):

You could achive it using the write function of the window document as follows:

```
public openNewTab(blob: Blob | string) {
   const data = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(blob);
   var myWindow = window.open("", '_blank');
   myWindow.document.write(data);
   setTimeout(() => window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data), 100);
}
```

You will find more details at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp .

Comment: document.write() and changing data type to text/html doesn't work. It opens tags as a text content again. I need to display HTML.