# How to open a string as plain text in a new tab with Javascript (in Firefox)?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow browsing of a JavaScript string by having a button, which opens the string contents as plain text in a new tab. So I tried this example in Firefox 115:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>Test open</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <h1>Test dl</h1>
  <button type="button" id="btn-open-tab">Open text in new tab</button>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function openNewTab(blob) { // from https://stackoverflow.com/q/67290024
    const data = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(blob);
    console.log(data)
    window.open(data, '_blank');
    setTimeout(() => window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data), 100);
  }

  let my_text_str = "Hello!\nThis is an example text.\nJust trying this out...\n";

  let btn_open_tab = document.getElementById("btn-open-tab");
  btn_open_tab.onclick = function(elem) {
    openNewTab(my_text_str);
  };
  </script>
</html>
```

If I click the button in Firefox 105, I can see a new tab being opened, and then it gets closed immediately - with a warning printout in the console:

> Storage access automatically granted for origin “null” on “`http://127.0.0.1:8000`”.

... if I check using a local server (`python3 -m http.server`); or:

> Storage access automatically granted for origin “null” on “null”.

... if I open the .html file using the `file:///` protocol.

I guess this message is supposed to warn me of something, but I cannot tell what it is - "automatically granted" implies that something succeeded, so I cannot see what is wrong.

So, how can I open string contents in a new tab for more than a millisecond (actually, for as long as the user wants - until the tab is closed manually) using JavaScript (hopefully in all browsers, not just Firefox)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an object URL instead.

```js
function openNewTab(text) {
    const blob = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```